# Need a way to access file in R that contains a list of vectors of strings & compare each vector to another txt file in which has string of 130 letters

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe, package

For R programming language -
Need a way to access a file that contains a list of vectors of strings (all vectors are of same length = 11), & to compare each element of this file to another file which has a single string of 130 letters.

All these letters are sequences of a protein.

I want to check if any single one of 11 letter sequence present in the file matches the 130 letter sequence I have with me in another file.

Also, the 11 letters seq need to be present in the 130 letters seq file in the same order.

E.g. - ACD, DEG, BCD, ADE, EBC

The whole sequence : ABCDEFGHIJK

(In this case the only third sequence matches perfectly.)

Kindly guide me through this as I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borrowing data from @K_D, you can try a base R option, i.e., `sapply` + `grepl`, like below

```
> sapply(short_strs,grepl,x = long_str,USE.NAMES = FALSE)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

The library `stringr` is useful for dealing with strings.

```
> library(stringr)
> long_str <- "ABCDEFGHIJK"
> short_strs <- c("ACD", "DEG", "BCD", "ADE", "EBC")
> str_detect(long_str,short_strs)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution you provided, i want to know if there's a way in which we can insert a file of strings in place of typing strings in the "short_strs" section... because i have about 300 short strings and typing them manually is not possible.

Comment: As mentioned by @Alexlok, if you have a .txt file with the 300 short strings with one string per line, you just have to type `short_strs<-readLines(path to your file/yourfile.txt)`

Comment: the type of my file is .xlsx

Answer (score 0):

What is the format of your files? If they are one string per line, you can use `readLines()`, then K_D's answer will work easily.

If they are FASTA, the package `Biostrings` from [Bioconductor](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biostrings.html) provides some useful functions:

```
library(BioStrings)
shrt_patterns <- readAAStringSet("file1.fa")
long_protein <- readAAStringSet("file2.fa")
countPDict(shrt_patterns, long_protein)
```